# Emacs auto-complete mode for Groovy?

Tags: emacs, groovy, autocomplete

Is there a Groovy compatible auto-complete mode for emacs?

I also was not able to find a keyword dictionary that I can use with [emacs autocomplete](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoComplete).

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there is no working (intelligent) auto-complete for Groovy. If you are inclined to a bit of hacking, the easiest way to achieving this would be to modify [emacs-eclim](https://github.com/senny/emacs-eclim/) (an Emacs package for talking to Eclipse) to work with the [Eclipse Groovy plugin](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Eclipse+Plugin). Shouldn't be that bad, as there is existing code for working with Eclipse Java that you could use as scaffolding.

HTH and sorry :(

Answer (score 3):

I have 'hacked' both [emacs-eclim](https://github.com/yveszoundi/emacs-eclim) and [Eclim](https://github.com/yveszoundi/eclim) to get code completion, not pretty or feature-complete, good enough for few hours of work.

**1. Notes**:

- **Code completion** is supported, but it is slow with auto-complete-mode sometimes, especially when completion is triggered automatically. I use *TAB* to start the *autocomplete* popup and *ALT-TAB* for the completions buffer, if I'm looking up all possible completions.
- **Source update for issues reporting** is supported but not fully accurate. As you save the buffer an incremental build is performed and the errors report is available (Problems via *C-c C-e o*.

If using auto-complete, set the following:

```
(ac-set-trigger-key "TAB")
(setq ac-auto-start nil)
```

**2. Installation**

- git clone https://github.com/yveszoundi/eclim
- cd eclim && ant -Declipse.home=YOUR_ECLIPSE_FOLDER
- git clone https://github.com/yveszoundi/emacs-eclim
- Add *emacs-eclim* folder to your *load-path*

**3. Sample Emacs configuration via [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) and ELPA.**

If you don't use use-package, adapt as needed...

```
(use-package eclim                                                                                                               
  :ensure emacs-eclim // overwrite ELPA install with my copy                                                                                                           

  :init (setq help-at-pt-display-when-idle t                                                                                     
              eclimd-default-workspace "~/Documents/workspace/"                                                                  
              help-at-pt-timer-delay 0.1)                                                                                        

  :config (progn (help-at-pt-set-timer)                                                                                          
                 (mapc #'require '(eclimd auto-complete-config))                                                                 
                 (ac-config-default)                                                                                             
                 (add-hook 'groovy-mode-hook 'auto-complete-mode)                                                                
                 (require 'ac-emacs-eclim-source)                                                                                
                 (ac-emacs-eclim-config)                                                                                         

                 (defun ers/eclim-run-class ()                                                                                   
                   (interactive)                                                                                                 
                   (beginning-of-buffer)                                                                                         
                   (search "class ")                                                                                             
                   (forward-word)                                                                                                
                   (eclim-run-class))                                                                                            

                 (bind-keys :map eclim-mode-map                                                                                  
                            ("C-c C-e l m" . eclim-manage-projects)                                                              
                            ("C-c C-e l r" . ers/eclim-run-class)                                                                
                            ("C-c C-e l c" . garbage-collect)                                                                    
                            ("C-c C-e l b" . eclim-project-build))                                                               

                 (add-hook 'groovy-mode-hook                                                                                     
                           (lambda ()                                                                                            
                             (remove 'ac-source-clang 'ac-sources)                                                               
                             (eclim-mode t)))                                                                                    

                 (add-hook 'java-mode-hook                                                                                       
                           (lambda ()                                                                                            
                             (remove 'ac-source-clang 'ac-sources)                                                               
                             (eclim-mode t)))))
```